# Trigger a command from one user control and handle it in the view model of another

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In Commands.cs, a command is defined:

```
public static readonly RoutedUICommand Account_OpenDetails 
            = new RoutedUICommand("show account details", 
                                  "Account_OpenDetails", 
                                   typeof(MainWindow));
```

In `UserControl1View` I have:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="LocalCommands:Command.Account_OpenDetails" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding AccountId}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In `UserControl2View` I want to do this:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="LocalCommands:Command.Account_OpenDetails" 
                        Executed="{Binding Account_OpenDetails}" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

And I was hoping this would invoke the following method in `UserControl2ViewModel` (which is the DataContext of `UserControl2View`):

```
public void Account_OpenDetails(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
```

Instead, I am getting:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to
>   type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.

Basically, from the XAML of one user control I want to trigger a Command, which is handled in the view model of another user control. I can handle this in the `.cs` of the `UserControl2View`, but I don't want to. I want it to be handled in the view model.

What is the correct syntax? I am open to any other ideas, as long as I achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, from the XAML of one user control I want to trigger a Command, which is handled in the view model of another user control

Create a shared Boolean flag on the primary view model which will flag the second control. Follow these steps.

1. Create a notified `Boolean` flag (say `IsAccountDetailsOpen`) on the main viewmodel.
2. Create a `Boolean` dependency property **with a change handler** on the secondary control. In the change handler method do what needs to be done per the control's view model which you mentioned.
3. On the main page bind the dependency property to `IsAccountDetailsOpen` of the second control.
4. Either in the commanding code, change the Boolean flag `IsAccountDetailsOpen` to `true` when the event happens to signal the second control.
5. -0r- create a Boolean dependency on the first control with a two way binding and set `IsAccountDetailsOpen` to true, to signal the other control.